# Transportar states entre componentes ReactJS de níveis diferentes

Tags: react, next.js

Estou tentando componentizar um menu de uma aplicação React/NextJS, e estou com dificuldades ao implementar os estados necessários.

Quando tenho tudo em um componente apenas, fica simples manipular os estados do que está aberto ou fechado, porém, o código ficou muito grande, e resolvi desmembrá-lo em diferentes componentes pra facilitar a manutenção futura. E aqui começou os problemas.

Meu componente pai é o **`<Nav />`**

```
import { useState } from 'react'

import BusinessAside from './megamenu/business/aside'
import BusinessOnDemand from './megamenu/business/ondemand'
import BusinessSelect from './megamenu/business/select'

export default function Nav(props) {

    let [isBusinessOpen, setIsBusinessOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href='#' onClick={() => {
                    setIsBusinessOpen(!isBusinessOpen);
                }}>Empresas</a>
                <div className={!isBusinessOpen ? "hidden" : ""}>
                    <div>
                        <BusinessAside />
                        <BusinessOnDemand />
                        <BusinessSelect />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    )
}
```

Quando clico no primeiro link, gostaria de abrir o meu mega-menu (a DIV logo abaixo). Até aí, sem problemas (isBusinessOpen vira true, e o menu é aberto).

Porém, vejam que dentro desta DIV, tenho 3 outros componentes.

**`<BusinessAside />`**

Após o menu ser aberto, eu tenho outros 2 links (Ondemand e Select).
Enquanto um deverá ter estado = true, o outro será false. Desta maneira, não teriamos 2 abertos ao mesmo tempo. Consegui fazer com que inicialmente o Ondemand seja aberto por default (true) e o Select fechado.

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function BusinessAside() {

    let [isOnDemandOpen, setIsOnDemandOpen] = useState(true);
    let [isSelectOpen, setIsSelectOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <aside>
            <a href="#" onClick={() => {
                    setIsOnDemandOpen(true);
                    setIsSelectOpen(false);
                }}>
                <p>On-Demand</p>
            </a>
            <a href="#" onClick={() => {
                    setIsOnDemandOpen(false);
                    setIsSelectOpen(true);
                }}>
                <p>Select</p>
            </a>
        </aside>
    )
}
```

O maior problema vem agora.

O click para definir se o Select deve estar aberto, está no componente **BusinessAside**.
Mas o comportamento que faz ele abrir/fechar, está dentro do componente **`<Select/>`**

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function BusinessSelect(props) {

    return (
        <section className={!isSelectOpen ? 'hidden' : ''}>
            <h1>Teste Select</h1>
        </section>
    )
}
```

Também tenho o componente OnDemand, que, ao mudar o isOnDemandOpen para true (state setado em ASIDE), deverá ser mostrado.

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function BusinessOnDemand(props) {

    return (
        <section className={!isOnDemandOpen ? 'hidden' : ''}>
            <div>
                <h1>OnDemand</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
```

Eu estou estagnado, sem saber como trafegar com estas states entre os componentes.
Pensando que a solução mais simples envolva useContext, criei um componente chamado **`<State />`**, e ele envolve toda a aplicação no _app.js

```
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

const AppContext = createContext();

export function AppWrapper({ children }) {

    const sharedState = {
        
    }

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={sharedState}>
            {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
}

export function useAppContext() {
    return useContext(AppContext);
}
```

E meu _app.js está da seguinte maneira.

```
import { AppWrapper } from '../context/state';

function Application({ Component, pageProps }) {

    return (
        <>
            <AppWrapper>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </AppWrapper>
        </>
    )
}

export default Application
```

Tenho um exemplo do comportamento esperado que subi neste link:
https://elated-franklin-1b5b5b.netlify.app/

Neste exemplo acima, eu deixei toda a estrutura do menu em um componente apenas, sendo simples a utilização do state. Então, o funcionamento acima é o esperado, para análise.

Comment: Use um estado por fora ou global esse é a minha indicação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem duas alternativas, utilizar prop drilling e controlar os estados no componente pai ou utilizar a Context API.

Context API:

Poderia criar o contexto desta forma e criar nele os estados que quer manipular em arquivos diferentes:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';

export const AppContext = createContext();

function AppWrapper({ children }) {
  const [isOnDemandOpen, setIsOnDemandOpen] = useState(true);
  const [isSelectOpen, setIsSelectOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        isOnDemandOpen,
        setIsOnDemandOpen,
        isSelectOpen,
        setIsSelectOpen,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useApp() {
  const context = useContext(AppContext);

  return context;
}

export { AppWrapper, useApp };
```

Com o contexto criado, você precisa envolver o children do app pelo contexto (você mostrou que já fez isso).

Por fim, basta instanciar o hook useApp e chamar as funções para manipular/acessar os estados nos componentes que quiser, um exemplo abaixo:

```
import React from 'react';

import { useApp } from '../caminho/do/contexto';

export default function BusinessAside() {
  const {
    setIsOnDemandOpen,
    setIsSelectOpen,
    isOnDemandOpen,
    isSelectOpen,
  } = useApp();

  console.log('isOnDemandOpen', isOnDemandOpen);
  console.log('isSelectOpen', isSelectOpen);

  return (
    <aside>
      <a
        href="#"
        onClick={() => {
          setIsOnDemandOpen(true);
          setIsSelectOpen(false);
        }}
      >
        <p>On-Demand</p>
      </a>
      <a
        href="#"
        onClick={() => {
          setIsOnDemandOpen(false);
          setIsSelectOpen(true);
        }}
      >
        <p>Select</p>
      </a>
    </aside>
  );
}
```

Caso precisar acessar os estados em outro componente, basta fazer da mesma forma que foi feito no acima.

Comment: Fred, acabei esquecendo de atualizar o status disso, mas fiz exatamente como sugeriu, usando a Context API, de forma muito similar a sua!